# How to split a string value in json and convert to nested objects using jq?

Tags: json, openstreetmap, geojson, jq

I am trying to use jq to convert something like this:

```
[
  {
    "type": "Feature",
    "properties": {
      "osm_id": "172544",
      "highway": "crossing",
      "other_tags": "\"crossing\"=>\"uncontrolled\",\"tactile_paving\"=>\"yes\""
    },
    "geometry": {
      "type": "Point",
      "coordinates": [
        13.3432342,
        52.5666157
      ]
    }
  }
]
```

into this:

```
[
  {
    "type": "Feature",
    "properties": {
      "osm_id": "172544",
      "highway": "crossing",
      "other_tags": {
        "crossing": "uncontrolled",
        "tactile_paving": "yes"
      }
    },
    "geometry": {
      "type": "Point",
      "coordinates": [
        13.3432342,
        52.5666157
      ]
    }
  }
]
```

right now, this is my progress:

```
jq 'map(try(.properties.other_tags |= split(",") // .)) | map(try(.properties.other_tags[] |= split("=>") // .)) | map(try(.properties.other_tags[] |= { (.[0]) : .[1] } // .))' example.json
```

but the output of "other_tags" looks like this:

```
  "other_tags": [
    {
      "\"crossing\"": "\"uncontrolled\""
    },
    {
      "\"tactile_paving\"": "\"yes\""
    }
  ]
```

I am pretty sure this is not as performant as it could be.

It's used to transform osm exports, which are fairly big

Is there a more elegant/shorter jq instruction i can use, also giving me the desired output as stated above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found a satisfying solution while fiddling around on [jqplay](http://jqplay.org):

```
jq '.features
  | map(try(.properties.other_tags |=
            (split("\",\"")
             | join("\"##strsplit##\"")
             | split("##strsplit##")
             | .[] |= split("=>") 
             | .[] |= {(.[0][1:-1]): (.[1][1:-1])}
             | add)) // .)'
```

edit: changed the array index, thanks to peak for your comment

edit2: comma tolerant and includes nodes w/o 'other_tags'

Comment: FYI, `.[0]|.[1:(length-1)]` can be abbreviated to `.[0][1:-1]`

Answer (score 2):

You could also use this:

```
<file jq '[.[] | try(.properties.other_tags |= ("{" + gsub("=>"; ":") + "}" | fromjson))//.]'
```

This adds curly braces `{` and `}` to the wanted string and replace `=>` by `:`. The string is then converted as a JSON object with the command `fromjson`.

The command doesn't change the JSON data if the `.properties.other_tags` isn't found.

Comment: other_tags is not always present, any chance i skip null returns?

Comment: thanks for your response, already tried that but it doesn't seem to work. you can have a look here: https://jqplay.org/s/YSlHL6iqb5

Comment: This approach can be made a bit less restrictive by changing the `gsub` to `gsub("\"=>\""; "\": \"")`

Comment: this works now, thanks alot. it also respects commas in values compared to my solution. but on the other hand its relatively slow. my current solution takes 41.81s, this one 71.34s on a 171MB big json file. any way i can speed this up a fair amount? also its giving me a slightly bigger (6MB) result, did not find out what difference is yet

Comment: @PhilippKolb It's likely the command `fromjson` that takes some time. Removing it might end up with similar solution as yours with the pitfalls you're mentioning.

Comment: @PhilippKolb To reduce the output size, you can use option `-c` to get the compact JSON format.

Comment: @oliv its bigger regardless of the compact flag, still dont know if its a good or a bad thing.

Comment: i does some weird stuff, looking at the diffed result: 
10550266c10549183
<         "email": "info@hanfmuseum.de",
---
>         "em:l": "info@hanfmuseum.de",

Comment: also it does not work on values within 'other_tags' that have quotes :/

Comment: @PhilippKolb Please modify your question with a meaningful example showing the problem you have with this command.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution that assumes the input can be parsed into comma-separated segments matching the following regex (expressed as JSON):

```
"\"(?<key>[^\"]+)\"=>\"(?<value>[^\"]+)\""
```

```
# emit a stream
def unwrap:
  . as $s
  | if length==0 then empty
    else match( "\"(?<key>[^\"]+)\"=>\"(?<value>[^\"]+)\",?" )
    | (.captures|map({(.name): .string})|add), 
      ( $s[.length:]|unwrap)
    end
;

 map( .properties.other_tags |= ([unwrap]|from_entries) )
```

This approach has the (potential) advantage of allowing commas and occurrences of "=>" within the keys and values.  Of course the implementation can be robustified (e.g. using `try` as you have done), but I've kept it simple so you can easily make modifications to meet your more detailed requirements.